# Use raw SQL in an ORM query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to make edits or override the ORM's generated SQL with your own raw SQL? Or is the ORM expected to be flexible enough to build pretty much any query I could imagine?

Specifically here's the query I'm trying to make, perhaps it isn't too hard to build via the ORM anyway though I'm not able to see any obvious path to build it. Here's the model:

```
class AllocationStatus(Base):

    STATUS_RESERVED = 1
    STATUS_RELEASED = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_RESERVED, "Reserved"),
        (STATUS_RELEASED, "Released"),
    )

    __tablename__ = 'allocation_status'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    allocation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('allocation.id'))
    allocation = relationship('Allocation')
    status = Column(Integer())
```

The idea is that for a given foreign key ID for `allocation_id`, I would want to know the latest record in `allocation_status`.

In order to achieve this in raw SQL, the following query is what I'm aiming for:

```
SELECT allocation_status.*
FROM allocation_status
LEFT JOIN allocation_status allocation_status2
    ON allocation_status.allocation_id = allocation_status2.allocation_id
    AND allocation_status.id < allocation_status2.id
WHERE allocation_status2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build it by aliasing the Model first and then using that alias as the second table to an outer join.
The following assumes that you already have a session that is bound to a working engine:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
from sqlalchemy import and_


allocation_status2 = aliased(AllocationStatus)
session.query(AllocationStatus).\
    outerjoin(allocation_status2,
              and_(AllocationStatus.allocation_id == allocation_status2.allocation_id,
                   AllocationStatus.id < allocation_status2.id)).\
    filter(allocation_status2.id.is_(None)).all()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  If someone gives a toy example don't try to solve it with existing tools.  There are reasons you might want to use raw SQL mapped back to the ORM.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @Abdou is the proper way to go, but you could also run your textual SQL using [`Query.from_statement()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement):

```
session.query(AllocationStatus).\
    from_statement(text("""
        SELECT allocation_status.*
        FROM allocation_status
        LEFT JOIN allocation_status allocation_status2
               ON allocation_status.allocation_id = allocation_status2.allocation_id
              AND allocation_status.id < allocation_status2.id
        WHERE allocation_status2.id IS NULL;""")).\
    all()
```

Note the use of [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text).